# Modx login preHook breaks when invalid user

Tags: php, authentication, modx

I'm trying to add an auth control to validate if a user is already logged or not, to achieve this, Im using a login preHook and I based my work on this https://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=100027&page=3 and this is my final prehook code:

```
<?php
$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Running login preHook ");
if (!isset($_GET['service'])){
    $formFields = $hook->getValues();
    $username = $formFields['username'];
    $modx->user = $modx->getObject('modUser', array('username' => $username, ));
    //Agregarle validacion
    if (isset($modx->user)) {
        $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Captured usernames is ".$username. ' loaded user is ' . isset($modx->user));
        $profile = $modx->user->getOne('Profile');
        if (isset($profile)) {
            $extended = $profile->get('extended');
            $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Logged is ".$extended['logged'] );
            if ($extended['logged'] == '1') {
                  $url = $modx->makeURL(38, '',  array('userblocked' => $username), 'https');
                  $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Url is ".$url );
                  $modx->sendRedirect($url);
                  return false;
            }        
        } else {
            $errorMsg = "User profile for ".$username. " not found";
            $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, $errorMsg );
            $hook->addError('user',$errorMsg);
            return false;
        }
        
    } else {
        $errorMsg = "User ".$username. " not found";
        $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, $errorMsg );
        $hook->addError('user',$errorMsg);
        return false;
    }
    
} else {
    return true;    
}
```

When I try to login with a valid user, its working as expected, but when I type random gibberish on the login name I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/model/modx/modaccessibleobject.class.php:215 Stack trace: #0 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/model/modx/modaccessibleobject.class.php(36): modAccessibleObject->checkPolicy('load') #1 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/xpdo/xpdo.class.php(757): modAccessibleObject::_loadInstance(Object(modX), 'modChunk', 'modChunk', Array) #2 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/xpdo/om/xpdoquery.class.php(584): xPDO->call('modChunk', '_loadInstance', Array) #3 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/xpdo/om/xpdoquery.class.php(566): xPDOQuery->hydrateGraphParent(Array, Array) #4 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/xpdo/om/xpdoobject.class.php(539): xPDOQuery->hydrateGraph(Object(PDOStatement), true) #5 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/xpdo/xpdo.class.php(757): xPDOObject::loadCollectionGraph(Object(modX), 'modChunk', Array, Array, true) #6 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/xpdo/xpdo.class.php(1088): xPDO->call('modChunk', 'loadCollectionG...', Array) #7 /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/ in /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/model/modx/modaccessibleobject.class.php on line 215

My inner modx log only says:

[2020-10-20 12:24:30] (ERROR @ /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/114.include.cache.php : 2) Running login preHook
[2020-10-20 12:24:30] (ERROR @ /home/magdal31/coreM0dXF1L3s/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/114.include.cache.php : 29) User sdfasfa not found

Any idea on what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from a Modx community forum and adding it here just in case anyone else is having the same, or similar issue, here is the answer:

"You probably shouldn’t override $modx->user with null. Try if it works if you use"

```
$myuser = $modx->getObject('modUser', array('username' => $username, ));
//Agregarle validacion
if ($myuser) {
    $modx->user = $myuser;
    ...
```

instead of

```
$modx->user = $modx->getObject('modUser', array('username' => $username, ));
//Agregarle validacion
if (isset($modx->user)) {
   ....
```

https://community.modx.com/t/error-when-adding-prehook-to-login/3219/3?u=camicase82